# Can I activate the tap ability of a creature summoned last turn before I have to remove it to my hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We had this situation come in a game last night, and I wanted to make sure that we played it correctly and that I understood the rules.

Player A had an [Eiganjo Free-Riders](http://magiccards.info/sok/en/8.html) in play. During this turn, he cast an [Icatian Javelineers](http://magiccards.info/tsts/en/10.html). He then ended his turn. During the upkeep of his next turn, he targeted the Javelineers with the Free-Riders' ability and then responded by tapping the Javelineers to use their ability.

By my understanding, the Javelineers ability would resolve first and he'd get to do a point of damage. Then the Free-Riders' ability would resolve, returning the Javelineers to his hand, and allowing him to cast them again. That seemed to be within the rules.

However, I wasn't sure when the Javelineers' summoning sickness wore off. Does it wear off in time for him to use this ability before they get returned to his hand by the Free-Riders?

Comment: Sounds like he's using a combo to get a Javelin every turn, and it's perfectly reasonable and legal.

Comment: The Free-Riders' ability doesn't target, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, he can do this. The rule for summoning sickness is as follows:

> 302.6  A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been **under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began**. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the "summoning sickness" rule.

Emphasis mine. In this case, the creature was under his control continuously since his most recent turn (which is the current turn) began.